# How to get the fragment position

Tags: android

How to get the fragment position inside the parent activity of the fragment?

Comment: What do you mean by "position"? The pixel count from top?

Comment: I am using view pager with fragment and I need it's position

Comment: Call `viewPager.getCurrentItem()`

Comment: but my view pager is in the activity layout not in the fragment layout.fragment layout consist of single list view

Comment: `((YourActivity) getActivity()).getViewPager().getCurrentItem()` inside your fragment

Comment: I didn't see anything called getViewPager()

Comment: Of course there is anything because you haven't posted any code, how would I know how to get your view pager? I gave you an example. `getActivity()` returns reference to your activity, `getViewPager()` should return a reference to your view pager. If you don't have this method then simply implement it.

Comment: Thank you. I posted this as an answer to your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach inside your fragment: `((YourActivity) getActivity()).getViewPager().getCurrentItem()`.

The `getActivity()` returns reference to your activity, `getViewPager()` should return a reference to your view pager.